# react build statics not found on child routes

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

On production, static/ path is relative to child route and is not found, so chunks.js are not found

https://example.com/childroute/static/js/0.94731513.chunk.js

but it should be:

https://example.com/static/js/0.94731513.chunk.js

nginx conf:

```
location / {
    index  index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri.html /index.html
  }
```

package.json:

```
"homepage": ".",
```

webpack.config.prod.js:

```
const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === "./"
```

React router :

```
 import { Router } from "react-router-dom"
<Router history={ history } basename="/">
```

App routes :

```
<Switch>
        <Route exact path={ PATHS.root } component={ Accueil } />
        <Route exact path={ PATHS.projets } component={ Projets } />
        <Route path={ `${PATHS.projets}/:id` } component={ ProjetDetail } />
      </Switch>
```

manifest.json:

```
"start_url": ".",
```

Comment: Add your webpack `output` configurations and `context`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it, for some reason my webpack conf output.publicPath was set to "".

It should be `publicPath: "/",`